# Download Snapshot File with Maven from a remote repository

Tags: tomcat, maven-2, continuum, aether

I created a J2EE application. I used continuum to deploy it on a remote repository. Now i want to automatically download the latest SNAPSHOT war file from this remote repository to my local TOMCAT_HOME/webapps. I tried many ideas but no one works. I wanted to use the maven-metadata.xml it contains manyinformation about the project. Any ideas?

Comment: how about **rsync** via ssh tunel ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Aether](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/08/introducing-aether/). With some minor coding it will do the job for you. If you decide to go this way I can show a real-life example where Aether is used in order to manually download artifacts from Maven repos.

edit: Take a look at [jcabi-aether](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aether/) wrapper around Aether.